I can't use wagtail command after pip install
Firstly, I attempted to install wagtail from source the usual way :
pip install -e ."[testing,docs]" -U
But it always returned TypeError : excepted string or bytes.
I then tried to reinstall python and pip altogether.
Through many researches on stackoverflow, I found to try install with sudo.
Then It worked.
But when I do wagtail command, it returns :
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/wagtail", line 33, in <module>     sys.exit(load_entry_point('wagtail', 'console_scripts', 'wagtail')())   File "/usr/local/bin/wagtail", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point     return next(matches).load() StopIteration 

I desperate with Wagtail application for more than one month.
I'm hoping for your kind help please. Thanks community.

If you needed to use sudo, that probably means you skipped over the step about activating a virtualenv. Just wondering - did you run through the main Wagtail tutorial before trying to set up a developer instance? If not, I'd highly recommend that first, as it covers the general installation steps in more detail.
